# Adjoint of resolvent of self-adjoint, densely-defined operator on a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space, $T=T^*$ a densely-defined linear operator on $H$. Denote the *resolvent set* of $T$ as $\rho(T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}~|~T-\lambda$ has bounded, everywhere-defined inverse}, and define the *resolvent of $T$ at $\lambda$* to be the bounded, everywhere-defined operator $R_\lambda=(T-\lambda)^{-1}$ $(\lambda\in\rho(T))$.

How would I set about proving that $(R_\lambda)^* = R_{\smash{\overline{\lambda}}}$? I've been playing around with the inner product and the definition of $R_\lambda$ and I'm getting nowhere, so any hints of what sort of calculations to attempt would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $D_T$ be the domain of $T$. Then, since the resolvent $R_\lambda$ is invertible, we know that $R_\lambda^{-1}(D_T)$ is also dense. For $y \in R_\lambda^{-1}(D_T)$ and $x \in D_T$ we have

$$\begin{align}\newcommand{\inner}[2]{{\langle {#1}\mspace{-3mu}\mid\mspace{-3mu} {#2}\rangle}}
\inner{y}{x} &= \inner{(T-\lambda)R_\lambda y}{x}\\
&= \inner{R_\lambda y}{(T-\overline{\lambda})x}\\
&= \inner{y}{R_\lambda^\ast(T-\overline{\lambda})x}.
\end{align}$$

Since $R_\lambda^{-1}(D_T)$ is dense, we have $R_\lambda^\ast(T-\overline{\lambda})x = x$ for all $x\in D_T$.

Can you conclude $R_\lambda^\ast = R_{\overline{\lambda}}$ from that?

Comment: Then, by density of $D_T$, for any $y\in H$ and $\epsilon>0$ there is $x\in D_T$ with $\|y-x\|<\epsilon$, so $\|(R_\lambda^*-R_{\overline{\lambda}})y\| \leq \|(R_\lambda^*-R_{\overline{\lambda}})(y-x)\|+0 \leq \| R_\lambda^*-R_{\overline{\lambda}} \| \epsilon$, i.e., they are equal on the entirety of $H$. [By the way, for any $\lambda \in \rho(T)$, $R_\lambda^{-1}(D_T)$ is in fact $H$, since $R_\lambda$ is required to be everywhere-defined. This doesn't affect your argument, however.] Thanks very much for the pointer! :-)